# JavaFX 8.0 - How can I get a MouseEventHandle at title bar

Tags: mouseevent, javafx-8, mouselistener

I have implemented a EventHandler which gets the window-drag of the mouse:

```
public void mouseEventHandler(){
    final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
    view.getScene().setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            dragDelta.x = mainStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = mainStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
        }
    });
    view.getScene().setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            mainStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
            mainStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
            stage.setX(mainStage.getX());
            stage.setY(mainStage.getY() + view.getScene().getHeight() + 25);
        }
    });
}
```

I have two stages: mainStage and a stage, which is addicted to the coordinates of the mainStage. My problem is, that the stage only moves if I click in the window of the mainStage and drag it. But it won't move if I click the title bar of the window for removing.
How can I get the MouseEvent for the title bar?

Here is the show() method, so you can understand the Addiction:

```
public void show(Stage mainStage, MenuPresenter menuPresenter){
    this.model = new Model();
    this.view = new GameView(this.model);
    this.chatWatchView = new ChatWatchView();
    this.score = this.model.getScore();
    this.menuPresenter = menuPresenter;
    this.mainStage = mainStage;
    mainStage.setScene(view.getScene());
    mainStage.centerOnScreen();
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(chatWatchView.getScene());
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setX(mainStage.getX());
    stage.setY(mainStage.getY() + view.getScene().getHeight() + 25);
    stage.show();
    mainStage.show();

    startTimeline();
    activateEventHandler();
    mouseEventHandler();
    //view.setScore("Score: " + model.getScore());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. Consider to add listeners to `xProperty()` and `yProperty()` of your Stage, I think it will work better.
In my case I ended up with something like this

```
void updatePosition(double stageX, double stageY) {
    //...
}
```

And then

```
stage.xProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        updatePosition(newValue, stage.getY())   
}));
stage.yProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        updatePosition(stage.getX(), newValue)   
}));
```